# Match a string with regexp

Tags: regex, perl, tcl

I am having a string like

```
-------- AGG x y PORT-16385-INFO    ----------------------------+
```

I want to extract the "AGG x y PORT-16385-INFO ". However this pattern in not same. It can have any number of spaces inbetween .

Help me with the regexp to get the string.

I am using this regexp

```
regexp {\s+(.*)\-\-*} $a - am
```

Ouput

```
AGG PORT-16385-INFO    ---------------------------
```

this is not i want. Help me with regexp.

Comment: Your regexp roughly grabs "at least one whitespace some whatever one dash some dashes". That is not what you want I think. Please confirm your match target string is "AGG x y PORT-16385-INFO" or? Where excatly can the spaces occur in that one?

Comment: If this is really perl, you could do a much safer thing and trim the start and end with `s///`, e.g. `s/^-+ //; s/ -+\+$//;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'll assume your delimiter is at least two `-` long and is seperated via a space from the contents. Then a trivial regex like

```
--\s+(.*?)\s+--
```

would already work. The `*?` quantifier does non-greedy matching, to terminate as early as possible.

If this regex works depends strongly on allowed values and the exact format of your input, which you have not sufficiently explained.

I am also suprised you tagged this as Perl — I am quite sure your code isn't valid Perl code.

---

If you do not want to use the `.` character class, then we can rewrite it to match all non-hyphen characters or a single hyphen followed by a non-hyphen:

```
--\s+((?:[^-]+|-[^-])*)\s+--
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You might want to disallows newlines along the hyphens as well.

Comment: Sorry. This is a tcl code but i need this regex to use in perl. regexp is same. By the way can we use without .*? quantifier

Comment: @Nitesh using `.*` instead of `.*?` *might* work here, because I require a space character to be present before the hyphens. However, using the non-greedy version is generally safer.

Comment: Thanks . But see if you can give the regexp without .*?

Comment: The matches will look like "-- AGG x y PORT-16385-INFO    --", thus include leading and trailing dashes.

Comment: @mvw Yes, the matched substring does include these hyphens. However, the first capture group does not. If we do not want to have the hyphens in the matched substring, we'll have to use lookarounds: `(?<=--\s).*?(?=\s--)`

Comment: @mvw No, it will *match* that `$&`, but not capture that `$1`.

Comment: @amon: I didn't get "?:[^-]+". What is ?: in this

Comment: I like the railroad syntax diagram. How was it made?

Comment: @mvw This was edited in by [Broxzier](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1745452/broxzier), who used the [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/) website.

Comment: @TLP: Thanks for the explanantion, so the parentheses group and the perl engine allows to access that group.

Answer (score 3):

Using `.*?` can work, like amon says, however, I sometimes find that the non-greedy quantifier is somewhat unpredictable. You can use anchors to make the greedy quantifier do the same thing:

```
^-+ (.*) -+\+$
```

Here we require the string to start and end with the specified sequence of dashes (and a plus sign at the end), so the greedy match is not allowed to match too much.

Answer (score 1):

In tcl, you easily handle it using string trim.

```
set a "-------- AGG x y PORT-16385-INFO    ----------------------------+"
set b [string trim $a +-]; # to remove all + and -
set b [string trim $b]; # to remove all the white spaces
puts $b
```